# Buscar un elemento de un struct en una list

Tags: c++, lista

dada esta estructura:

```
struct Libro{
string nombre;
int codigo;
bool disp;
};
```

y esta list `list <Libro> libro;`

me gustaria saber como buscar un libro en especifico mediante el codigo, osea algo asi que el usuario coloque el codigo y muestre el nombre, el codigo y la disponibilidad.. me comentaron que con std:find_if y lo he probado con vectores de enteros o listas de enteros.. pero no encuentro como hacer que funcione cuando se trata de list de structs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la siguiente parte te muestro un ejemplo usando el struct Libro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

struct Libro{
    std::string nombre;
    int codigo;
    bool disp;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Libro &l)
{
    return o << l.nombre << ' ' << l.codigo << ' ' << l.disp;
}

static bool buscar_por_codigo(const Libro & libro, int n){
    return libro.codigo == n;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<Libro> libros = { {"libro1", 1, true},
                                {"libro2", 4, false},
                                {"libro3", 2, false},
                                {"libro4", 5, false}};

    int n = 2;
    std::list<Libro>::iterator it = std::find_if(libros.begin(),
                                                 libros.end(),
                                                 std::bind(&buscar_por_codigo,
                                                           std::placeholders::_1,
                                                           n));
    if(it != libros.end())
        std::cout << *it <<"\n";
    else
        std::cout << "No hay coincidencias\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me han ayudado un monton.. la funcion static bool la habia visto en una guia pero era con clases no tenia ni idea de como pasarlo a estructuras normales.. parece que para trabajar a fondon con los contenedores tendre que familiarizarme con la sobrecarga de operadores, para que es la libreria functional?

Comment: @MarcelSalazar es la manera más limpia y moderna de hacerlo, no ahorra lineas de código, si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el [tour], esa es la mejor forma de agradecer.

Comment: @MarcelSalazar la librerias functional es necesario para usar std::bind, std::placeholders_XXX, te recomiendo leer la documentación si deseas más detalles de las funciones e importaciones.

Answer (score 2):

> Me comentaron que con `std:find_if` y lo he probado con vectores de enteros o listas de enteros.. pero no encuentro como hacer que funcione cuando se trata de `list` de `structs`.

Es indiferente usar [`std:find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) con vectores o listas de cualquier tipo de dato, las funciones de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) son plantillas preparadas para recibir cualquier [iterador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator). En concreto, la manera más habitual de usar la función `std:find_if` es usando la sobrecarga que recibe dos iteradores (inicio y final) y un [predicado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicado_(l%C3%B3gica)#L%C3%B3gica-matem%C3%A1tica) unario.

El predicado es una función, lambda o funtor que espera recibir una instancia del dato a buscar y debe devolver `false` si no coincide con el criterio de búsqueda o `true` en caso contrario; si encuentra un elemento cuyo predicado devuelva `true` finaliza la búsqueda y devuelve el iterador que señala al elemento encontrado o el iterador final en caso contrario.

Por lo tanto, tu código de búsqueda podría parecerse a esto:

```
std::list<Libro> libros{ /* rellenar con datos */ };
int codigo;

std::cout << "Código a buscar: ";
std::cin >> codigo;

auto l = std::find_if(libros.begin(), libros.end(), [&codigo](const Libro &l)
{
    return l.codigo == codigo;
});

if (l == libros.end())
    std::cout << "El libro con código " << codigo << " no ha sido encontrado.";
else
    std::cout << "Libro encontrado " << *l;
```

Comment: me referia a que cuando son vectores  o las mismas list de enteros osea un solo dato  `{1,2,3,4,5}` pero con estructuras no tenia ni idea.. porque para comparar un tiene que hacer `libro.codigo==codigo`.. pero no me imaginaba como aplicarlo.. pero muchas gracias.. me imagino que para editar por ejemplo la disponibilidad debo usar una sobrecarga de istream no?

Comment: no se a qué te refieres con lo de "*editar la disponibilidad*" ¿podrías reformular la duda?

Comment: era editar cualquier dato dentro de un contenedor pero no importa de tanto darle lo encontre.. no habia caido en cuenta como funcionaba bien el iterador..  encontre que con (*iterador).elemento podia acceder a un dato especifico dentro del contenedor luego de buscar por ejemplo un libro en especifico.